# Why is a native exception fired in the implementation of the Matrix class?

Tags: c++

I am writing an implementation of the Matrix class. The copy operator has a check to see if the sizes of the matrices match. If you run this version of the program:

```
Matrix<int> mat1(3,3);
Matrix<int> mat2(3,3);
mat1.fillMatrix();
mat2.fillMatrix();

Matrix<int> mat3 = mat1 - mat2;
```

Everything works great. But if you do so

```
Matrix<int> mat1(3,3);
Matrix<int> mat2(3,3);
mat1.fillMatrix();
mat2.fillMatrix();

Matrix<int> mat3;//or Matrix<int> mat3(3,3)
mat3 = mat1 - mat2;
```

An exception is thrown from my constructor, here it is:

```
    Matrix() : data(nullptr), rows(0), cols(0) {}

Matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols) : data(static_cast<T *>(operator new[](sizeof(T) * rows * cols, static_cast<std::align_val_t>(alignof(T))))), rows(rows), cols(cols) {}

Matrix &operator=(Matrix<T> &&other) noexcept
{
    if (&other == this)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    if (rows != other.rows || cols != other.cols)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Error assigning matrices of different sizes");
    }

    clean();

    std::swap(data, other.data);
    std::swap(rows, other.rows);
    std::swap(cols, other.cols);

    other.data = nullptr;
    other.rows = 0;
    other.cols = 0;

    return *this;
}
```

I understand that the default constructor is called, which sets the rows and columns to 0, so an exception is thrown, but why does everything work well in the first case, but not in the second? Is it possible to fix it somehow?

Comment: The first case doesn't call the default constructor and instead calls the copy constructor

Comment: In the first case, you don't default construct and then assign: you copy construct.

Comment: "implementation of the Matrix class" What is **the** Matrix class anyway? I am not aware of any such classes in the C++ standard library.

Comment: But I suppose it should work in both cases?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili, This is my class implementation where STL cannot be used, everything has to be done manually

Comment: Why is assigning a matrix to one with a different size an error? Your assignment operator should copy the data (including the number of rows and columns) into the matrix.

Comment: @Kevin, In order not to copy a 1x1 matrix to a 10x10 matrix

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко But what's wrong with that? The 10x10 matrix will then become a 1x1 matrix.

Comment: The only reason to not allow this would be if the size of the matrix was part of the type, e.g. assigning a `Matrix<int, 3, 3>` to a `Matrix<int, 5, 5>` doesn't make sense. But then your assignment operator would only take the matrix of the right size, so you wouldn't need the check at all. And the default constructor would create a matrix of the right size to begin with.

Comment: I just don’t understand how in the assignment constructor to make a 1x1 matrix from a 10x10 matrix

Comment: On a side note: your 2nd constructor is needlessly over-complicated, it can be greatly simplified: `Matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols) : data(new T[rows * cols]), rows(rows), cols(cols) {}` Just make sure you also implement `~Matrix() { delete[] data; }` per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Also, your assignment operator is leaking memory, you need to get rid of `other.data = nullptr;` (and `other.rows = 0; other.cols = 0;`)

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко Your assignment operator as it is right now would already do that! You're changing the only 3 data members that matter: data, rows, and cols

Answer (score 0):

Use SmallMatrix or Matrix to get type safe Matrixes:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols>
class SmallMatrix {
public:
    const T * operator[](std::size_t x) const {
        return data[x];
    }
    T * operator[](std::size_t x) {
        return data[x];
    }
    T data[rows][cols]{};
};

template <typename T, std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols>
class Matrix {
private:
    T *data{new T[rows * cols]};
public:
    Matrix() { }
    ~Matrix() {
        delete[] data;
        data = nullptr; // crash on use after free
    }
    Matrix(const Matrix &other) {
        *this = other;
    }
    Matrix(T &&other) : data(other.data) {
        other.data = nullptr;
    }
    Matrix & operator=(const Matrix &other) {
        if constexpr (std::is_aggregate_v<T>) {
            memcpy(data, other.data, sizeof(T) * rows * cols);
        } else {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
                for (std::size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                    (*this)[i][j] = other[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Matrix operator=(Matrix &&other) {
        swap(data, other.data);
        return *this;
    }
    const T * operator[](std::size_t x) const {
        return &data[x * cols];
    }
    T * operator[](std::size_t x) {
        return &data[x * cols];
    }
    Matrix(const T (&other)[rows][cols]) {
        if constexpr (std::is_aggregate_v<T>) {
            memcpy(data, other, sizeof(T) * rows * cols);
        } else {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
                for (std::size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                    (*this)[i][j] = other[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Matrix(T (&&other)[rows][cols]) {
        if constexpr (std::is_aggregate_v<T>) {
            memcpy(data, other, sizeof(T) * rows * cols);
        } else {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
                for (std::size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                    std::swap((*this)[i][j], other[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Matrix a{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}};
    Matrix b{a};
    Matrix<double, 5, 8> m;
    std::cout << b[0][0] << " " << b[0][1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << b[1][0] << " " << b[1][1] << std::endl;
}
```